# Shape morphing algorithm?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, shapes, tween

Is there a way to replicate by code what Flash Pro/CC does when you `tween` a shape into another one? Maybe a library is already out there?

Or, is it possible accessing some API within AS3 itself?

Answer (score 1):

In AS3 you can include:
`import fl.transitions.Tween;`
However, this does not solve your issue; Tween within AS3 only allows you to Tween a static object, so you are left with two options:

1. Creating the MorphShape object in the Flash authoring tool, or
2. coordinate manipulation of the shape (which seems unrealistic)

Comment: Thanks for the input. Sadly I can't use the fl library since I'm developing in FlashDevelop (and , as you said, that doesn't immediately solve the problem anyway).